# C++ problems, my two source codes should have the same output but they are different

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I am trying to figure out why these two C++ source have different outputs, when they should be outputing the same thing. the first source code is:

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0, k = 0;
    while (sum <= 25000)
    {
        k = k + 1;
        sum = sum + k;
    }
    cout << "The last number added is " << k << " for the end result of " << sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

The next source code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0, k;
    for (k = 1; sum <= 25000; k = k + 1)
        sum = sum + k;
    cout << "The last number added is " << k << " for the end result of " << 
sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain to be why one outputs the variable k as 224 and the other 225? I am new to this and maybe don't fully understand the in's and out's of C++.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: in the first your `k` starts from `0`, the other one it starts from `1`

Comment: That's because the for will execute the `k = k + 1` and then do the test. Your while do the test and then increment k. So in the for, the k will always be one too much after the for

Comment: @drescherjm But he adds 1 before adding to `sum`, so they both actually start at `1`. The difference is in where they end.

Comment: @drescherjm but the first one started at 0 and incremented k before doing anything with it anyway

Comment: Put `printf("%d\n", k)` right before `sum = sum + k;` in both programs and you'll see the difference.

Comment: And to keep the output from going on forever, I suggest you stop at 5 or 10, not 2500.

Comment: Problem lies at the termination statement. Case1 will exit the loop when sum>25000, but `K` will increment even when `sum<=25000` is met. But in Case2: loop will stop and `K` will not increment.

Comment: @sma, how would you reword the termination statement to make it stop and not increment?

Comment: Start both loops with same value and keep increment in the ending of loop body. That should give same output.

Answer (score 1):

In the first loop

```
while (sum <= 25000)
{
    k = k + 1;
    sum = sum + k;
}
```

the evaluation of the next value of the variable `k` is done before the statement

```
    sum = sum + k;
```

So the variable `k` can not be increased if `sum > 25000`

In this loop

```
for (k = 1; sum <= 25000; k = k + 1)
    sum = sum + k;
```

the evaluation of the next value of the variable `k` is done after the statement

```
    sum = sum + k;
```

So the variable `k` is increased the last time when `sum > 25000`.

You can rewrite the second loop the following way to get identical results.

```
int sum = 0, k;
for (k = 0; sum <= 25000; )
{
    k = k + 1;
    sum = sum + k;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Output is different as the behavior of incrementing k is different in for and while loops.

output 1:
 k: 223 sum: 24976
 k: 224 sum: 25200

The last number added is 224 for the end result of 25200

In while loop test is done first and then k is incremented.
output 2:
 k: 223 sum: 24976
 k: 224 sum: 25200

The last number added is 225 for the end result of 25200

In for loop k is incremented and then sum is tested against 25000

Answer (score 0):

Just Change your **First Program** to:

```
int main() 
{
    int sum = 0, k = 1;    // Set K = 1
    while (sum <= 25000)
    {
        sum = sum + k;    // First Add k to Sum 
        k = k + 1;        // Then Increment k
    }
    cout << "The last number added is " << k << " for the end result of " <<sum << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```